# Button array causes app to crash

Tags: java, android

I have multiple buttons in my app and I want to set the same text for every button using a loop. So I declared an array and filled it with the buttons in this manner:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1,b2,b3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    }

    Button[] buArray ={b1,b2,b3};

    void b1clicked(View view) {
        for (int i =0;i<3;i++) {
            buArray[i].setText("it works");
        }
    }
}
```

But when i try to set text for a button from the array like this

```
buArray[0].setText("some text");
```

This causes my app to crash and force closes 
And gives me an error like this in the the log 
"NullPointerException

Comment: Please post your full log,

Comment: Where did you put this line (`buArray[0].setText("some text")`)?

Comment: I didnt put that line exactly

Comment: You might like https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/3166697 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/3166697

Comment: There real answer here: subtle details often matter a lot. Therefore I tend to recommend newbies to first learn a but of pure Java before going for Android. It is complicated enough to understand in which order Java initializes fields, without the additional complexity of the Android onWhatever() methods...

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Button[] buArray ={b1,b2,b3};` is outside of the methods, it is initialized when the Activity object is created. At that point, `b1`, `b2` and `b3` are all `null`.

Move the initialization into the `onCreate()` method and it will work.

```
Button b1,b2,b3;
Button[] buArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buArray = new Button[] {b1, b2, b3};  
}
```

Comment: Wow i have alooot to learn . I think i tried that too and gave me the same result ... Am not home now ...will try it later

Comment: Rest assured, the answer is correct.